# Showing that a matrix is a orthogonal projector

Tags: orthogonality, least-squares

The matrix norm of the matrix in the matrix for matrix

Comment: The question needs a bit of attention.

Answer (score 1):

Assume that $X$ is a column vector that is a particular linear combination of columns of $Q$ plus something that is orthogonal to $\mathcal S$.

Work out what the elements of $Q^TX$ are, and then what $QQ^TX$ must be.

Comment: What are the elements of $Q^TX$ in this case? I'm not sure how to proceed from here

Comment: @poer1: Write $X=a_1Q_1+\ldots+a_kQ_k+U$ where $U\bot \mathcal S$, and work $Q^TX$ out explicitly.